# 8051 / EFM8LB1 / programming via C2 after PCON0.STOP := 1?

Tags: microcontroller, 8051

Yesterday I wanted to see, how much power my EFM8LB1 uses, when it has just this firmware with bootloader disabled:

```
.org 0
ljmp 1$
1$:
orl (REG01CN), #8
orl (PCON0), #2
```

Today I found, that I cannot access it via C2 anymore.
I tried keeping it in reset when powering on and then sending C2 commands... without success...

How can I fix it without dumping the MCU and soldering a new one?

How does that EFM8LB1 decide if the reset means "now we do C2" or "now you run the `reset ljmp`"?

Comment: check the datasheet

Comment: @jsotola i did. but: the datasheet is not very clear about my questions. after the reset it seems like the MCU starts to turn everything off, before i can send the "halt core" byte. but i dont understand why, because i only wait less than 5usec after reset and the code execution starts allegedly after appr. 50usec.

Answer (score 2):

seems like it is possible to "brick" a EFM8LB1 and EFM8UB2...
https://www.silabs.com/community/mcu/8-bit/forum.topic.html/efm8ub2_efm8lb1_noc2afterstop-PSub

not even a power-on-reset delay of >3msec helped in my case:
https://skybluetrades.net/unbricking-efm8ub3-thunderboard/

-arne

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions in the last messages of: https://www.silabs.com/community/mcu/8-bit/knowledge-base.entry.html/2015/08/20/_bricking_an_8-bit-54nh ?

Comment: @vangelo sure... i even used a pnp BJT and observed the voltage rise (it took appr. 800usec) and then i wrote the magic bytes and then i tried to erase the chip, but even that failed, although it needed less than 1500usec. It seems like it does not initialize the SFRs immediately after RST/C2CK goes high.